# Opening files by using a list?

Tags: python, json, list

EDIT: The way I wrote the question did not seam to get the answer I was looking for. Here is a shorter version of the question I think is more clear.

I want to take the following code and condense it int a single for loop.

```
with open("vzt_notes", "r") as working_vzt_notes:
    vzt_notes = json.load(working_vzt_notes)
with open("rms_notes", "r") as working_rms_notes:
    rms_notes = json.load(working_rms_notes)
with open("nsr_notes", "r") as working_nsr_notes:
    nsr_notes = json.load(working_nsr_notes)
with open("py_notes", "r") as working_py_notes:
    py_notes = json.load(working_py_notes)
with open("vzt_keys", "r") as vzt_kw:
    vzt_keys = json.load(vzt_kw)
with open("rms_keys", "r") as rms_kw:
    rms_keys = json.load(rms_kw)
with open("nsr_keys", "r") as nsr_kw:
    nsr_keys = json.load(nsr_kw)
with open("py_keys", "r") as py_kw:
    py_keys = json.load(py_kw)
```

Currently I open all of my files one at a time. As I am going to be creating many more files dynamically I want to have a for loop that will open all my files in the manor I am doing above. I have attempted a few for loops however all I can get to somewhat work is storing all the dictionaries from the files being opened into one big dictionary. I don't want to do it this way. I need to have the results from the for loop perform the same task as opening each file one at a time and naming the variable to be the same as the file name and storing the files contents in that variable.

Comment: You're not making use of `cname = startname+file`, you're just overwriting it. Looks like you got confused about your variable names.

Comment: There's no `file_name` anywhere. It this the actual code producing the error?

Comment: @Alex Hall I am using `cname`. it is at the end of the `with open`

Comment: @ dhke the `file_name` is just a place holder for the file name that is causing the error. In the case of the action that caused this error the file name was `vzt_notes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add new variables to the global scope programmatically. Why not store your notes in a dictionary instead? Here's a method to achieve what you want.

```
import json

def json_loader(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return json.load(f)


def load_files(filenames):
    return (json_loader(filename) for filename in filenames)


filenames = [
    'vzt_notes', 'rms_notes', 'nsr_notes',
    'py_notes', 'vzt_keys', 'rms_keys',
    'nsr_keys', 'py_keys',
]

vzt_notes, rms_notes, nsr_notes, \
    py_notes, vzt_keys, rms_keys, \
    nsr_keys, py_keys = load_files(filenames)

print(list(load_files(filenames)))
```

With the above approach, it may be better (safer) for maintaining your code to do this:

```
vzt_notes = json_loader('vzt_notes')
rms_notes = json_loader('rms_notes')
...
```

Comment: All my notes are stored in a dictionary on files. The list is used to store the names of each file so I can use that list to open all the files. edit: each string in the list corresponds with a filename for a different dictionary.

Comment: I see what this is doing. I had to run it to understand. So because this is storing all the dictionaries from the files in one big dictionary then I am going to have to change how all my other functions are looking for the dictionaries.

Comment: I guess I can do it this way. I am really trying to reproduce the first part of my code by using a for loop. I would rather not store each file (each file has a single dict) in a massive dictionary. I would like them to be imported into their own dictionary using the file name as the variable name.

Comment: I have simplified my question if you have the time to check it out. I think I was confusing the situation with my lengthy question.

Comment: Updated the answer to be what I think you want. But I think using an extra top-level dictionary would be better style.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was attempting to do. Edit: Question though. Can you explain the part with the file_name separated by commas = load_files(filenames). I have not seen this before. Can you have multiple variables = to something?

Comment: It's called tuple packing/unpacking. You can do this in Python: `x, y = 1, 2`. We return a list (really a generator) of json file data and unpack each element of the list into a single variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This make sense now. It does add a extra step to file loading that I need to figure out how to work around as I am wanting to be able to add these dictionary files from the Tkinter app but its a good start. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you're trying to achieve:

```
for file_suffix in file_list:
    prefix = "working_"
    filename = prefix + file_suffix
    with open(filename, "r") as file_obj:
        data = json.load(file_obj)
```

All I've done is change variable names so that they don't clash.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. It must be related to how my other functions are calling the file_name.

Comment: I have simplified my question if you have the time to check it out. I think I was confusing the situation with my lengthy question.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the file names, open each one, append the loaded file to a list which the function returns.

```
file_list =[ "vzt_notes","rms_notes","nsr_notes","py_notes","vzt_keys","rms_keys","nsr_keys","py_keys" ]

def loadFiles(event=None):
    loaded_file_list = []
    for filename in file_list:
        # You can reuse the file handle f
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            loaded_file_list.append(json.load(f))
    return loaded_file_list

loaded_files = loadFiles()
```